# Cron job - exported file emailed is blank

Tags: shell, cron-task

I am receiving the email from the following CRON job but with a blank file attached.  I have checked the /home/XXXXXX/public_html/tmp/ directory and a good tqhsa_hikashop_order.txt file is created in that /tmp/ folder but the one attached to the email that I receive is empty.

```
mysql --database=XXXXXXXX_jml_6UCHadruwR8veju3 -u XXXXXXXX_8eh6Nu --password=fRa6r7wRerEtuzud -B -e "SELECT order_number, order_created, order_invoice_number, order_full_price, order_discount_code, order_discount_price, order_payment_method, order_payment_price FROM tqhsa_hikashop_order;" > /home/XXXXXXXX/public_html/tmp/tqhsa_hikashop_order.txt | mail -s "Daily Discount Table Dump" -a /home/XXXXXXXX/public_html/tmp/tqhsa_hikashop_order.txt luke@example.com
```

Any ideas why the good text file is not being attached?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your first command finishes before running the second, so that the file exists on disk.

So essentially replace the `|` with a `&&`:

```
mysql \
  --database=XXXXXXXX_jml_6UCHadruwR8veju3 \
  -u XXXXXXXX_8eh6Nu \
  --password=fRa6r7wRerEtuzud \
  -B \
  -e "SELECT order_number, order_created, order_invoice_number, order_full_price, order_discount_code, order_discount_price, order_payment_method, order_payment_price FROM tqhsa_hikashop_order;" > /home/XXXXXXXX/public_html/tmp/tqhsa_hikashop_order.txt \
&& \
mail \
  -s "Daily Discount Table Dump" \
  -a /home/XXXXXXXX/public_html/tmp/tqhsa_hikashop_order.txt luke@example.com
```

To illustrate using an example:

```
myuser@myshell:~ $ echo "testing" > testy.txt | cat testy.txt
cat: testy.txt: No such file or directory

myuser@myshell:~ $ echo "testing" > testy.txt && cat testy.txt 
testing
```